# MultinomialNB - Theory vs practice

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, multinomial

OK so I'm just studying Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course. I'm currently reading [this chapter](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes2.pdf) and want to try the Multinomial Naive Bayes (bottom of page 12) for myself using SKLearn and Python. So Andrew proposes a method, in which each email in this case is encoded so

> We let `x_i` denote the identity of the `i`-th word in the email. Thus, `x_i` is now an integer taking values in `{1, . . . , |V|}`, where `|V|` is
>   the size of our vocabulary (dictionary). An email of n words is now
>   represented by a vector `(x1, x2, . . . , xn)` of length `n` **note that n
>   can vary for different documents**. For instance, if an email starts
>   with `“A NIPS . . . ,”` then `x_1 = 1` (`“a”` is the first word in the
>   dictionary), and `x2 = 35000` (if `“nips”` is the 35000th word in the
>   dictionary).

See highlights.

So this is also what I did in Python. I have a `vocabulary`, which is a list of 502 words, and I encoded each "email" so that it's represented the same way as Andrew describes, for example the message "this is sparta" is represented by `[495, 296, 359]` and "this is not sparta" by `[495, 296, 415, 359]`.

So here comes the problem.

Apparently, SKLearn's `MultinomialNB` requires input with uniform shape (I'm not sure about this, but as of now, I'm getting `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`, which I think is because the input vectors are not of same size).

So my question is, how can I use `MultinomialNB` for multiple length messages? Is it possible? What am I missing?

Here's some more of what I'm doing with code:

```
X = posts['wordsencoded'].values
y = posts['highview'].values
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
print(clf.predict())
```

What the input looks like:[image]
[image][image]

Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-933-dea987cd8603> in <module>()
      3 y = posts['highview'].values
      4 clf = MultinomialNB()
----> 5 clf.fit(X, y)
      6 MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
      7 print(clf.predict())

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    525             Returns self.
    526         """
--> 527         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
    528         _, n_features = X.shape
    529 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    508     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    509                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 510                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    511     if multi_output:
    512         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    371                                       force_all_finite)
    372     else:
--> 373         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    374 
    375         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are thinking right. You have to encode each mail with fixed length vector. This vector is called word count vector of 502 dimensions (in your case) for each email of training set.

Each word count vector contains the frequency of 502 dictionary words in the training file. Of course you might have guessed by now that most of them will be zero. for example : "this is not sparta not is this sparta" will be encoded like below. 
[0,0,0,0,0,.......0,0,2,0,0,0,......,0,0,2,0,0,...0,0,2,0,0,......2,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Here, all the four 2's are placed at 296th, 359th, 415th, 495th index of 502 length word count vector.

So, a feature vector matrix will be generated whose rows denote number of files of training set and columns denote 502 words of dictionary. 
The value at index ‘ij’ will be the number of occurrences of jth word of dictionary in ith file.

This generated encoding of emails(feature vector matrix), can be given to the MultinomialNB for training.

You will also have to generate similar 502 length encoding for test email also before predicting the class.

You can easily build a spam filter classifier with multinomialNB on ling-spam dataset using the following blog. The blog-post uses sklearn and python for implementation.

https://appliedmachinelearning.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/nlp-blog-post/

Comment: Thank you! So maybe the method I linked and the SKLearn multinomialNB are different methods? In the notes I linked (and as quoted), the algorithm can work with different lenghts.

Comment: In the chapter which you were reading, Fixed length encoding of each document is given on page 8 and thats how sklearn implements it in Multinomial NB. So, sklearn's method is described by Andrew Ng on page 8. The method you linked here which is at page 12-13 describes the event model for text classification. These two methods seems different.

Comment: Well, it's under the Naive Bayes subchapter (Naive Bayes is 2, the multinomial event model is chapter 2.2), so I guessed it was the multinomial variation of NB. SKLearn documentation also states that multinomialNB is "The multinomial Naive Bayes classifier".

Comment: Even a paper's abstract linked at the SKLearn documentation quotes "Some use a multi-variate Bernoulli model, that is, a Bayesian Network with no dependencies between words and binary word features. Others use a multinomial model, that is, a uni-gram language model with integer word counts.". However, it seems to me that SKLearn's multinomialNB still uses binary word features instead of integer word counts, so I'm quite a bit confused...

Comment: also, the page 8 method implements the Bernouilli NB, not the multinomial.

Comment: Sklearn MultinomialNB uses interger word counts [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html]. Sklearn BernoulliNB uses binary word features [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html]. It is clearly written there. I have edited my answer. Look at the word count vector in the answer now. Hope you are clear that the word count vector in my answer is integer word counts.

Comment: Also, You were right. I saw it again page 8 implements bernoulli NB. He has used binary word features only. Chapter 2.2 - The multinomial event model is quite different, atleast not at all like what sklearn's  MultinomialNB uses. In sklearn's implementation it will always take fixed length encoding be it Multinomial or Bernoulli. If the word is present in vocabulary, it will take 1(binary) in bernoulli and 'word count'(no. of occurances in the that email) in MultinomialNB.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I've checked the blog post you linked, and there is, in fact a much easier way to build a dictionary, than having to code it by hand. SKLearn has got you covered as described here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html
By using `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` you can get your raw text `multinomialNB`-ready in a jiffy. :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer buddy. I know CountVectorizer n all. I just wanted to do it by hand in the blog for the beginners to understand it in a hard way. Thanks again..My first accepted answer on stack overflow. :-D :-D